# Map a function to an iterator and get another iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I want to map a function `def func(x)` to an iterator `iterator` and get the result as another iterator

`map(func, iterator)` is giving me a `<map>` object, which has no `.next()` method implemented

```
AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Is it possible to perform such a map?

Comment: A map object _is_ an iterator. That doesn't mean it has a next method, that's not what the protocol requires.

Comment: It has a `__next__` method, which is what the `next` *function* looks for.

Comment: `.next` is part of the Python 2 protocol, in Python 3, it's `__next__`, but in *both* cases you should use the built-in `next(iterator)`, not `iterator.__next__()` or `iterator.next()`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the built-in [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function, which is called as a top-level function.

```
next(map(func, iterator))
```

this will return the next element, or raise `StopIteration` if you've hit the end. It can also be given an optional argument to return instead of raising `StopIteration` if the iterator is exhausted.

Internally, in Python 3 at least, `next` calls the `__next__` *method* on the object, so this is effectively the same as

```
map(func, iterator).__next__()
```

though it's bad practice to call dunder methods directly. You should use the built-in `next` function instead.